# How to change the color of the tilde characters indicating the filler lines after the last line of a buffer in Vim?

Tags: vim

When Vim starts, it displays the tilde symbol (`~`) for empty lines. Is there a way to change its color?

Comment: Related if not the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813059/is-it-possible-to-not-display-a-for-blank-lines-in-vim

Comment: Also related (and also not the same): https://stackoverflow.com/q/3725526/254635

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

```
:highlight NonText ctermfg=12
```

12 is the default color; change as you see fit.

Comment: But this affects visibility of the list chars at the same time!

Answer (score 17):

In Vim 8, you can set the `EndOfBuffer` highlight group separately from `NonText`:

```
highlight EndOfBuffer ctermfg=bg
```

Comment: `:help E420`: "This only works after setting the colors for the Normal group and for the MS-DOS console."

Comment: can you link to any site that teach me how to set the color? sry, im new to vim

Comment: Is it possible to completely deactivate the displaying of the tildes? Setting the color to the same as the background color of vim is a first step in the right direction, does not solve the problem for a transparent terminal though. Even with `highlight EndOfBuffer ctermfg=none`, they are still shown.

Comment: I posted a new answer about changing the fill character itself, instead of the color.

Answer (score 8):

Lucas is right but if you want to change the colour in gvim as well I think you need `guifg=` as well as `ctermfg=`

i.e. `:highlight NonText ctermfg=*color* guifg=*color*`

Answer (score 8):

I can't leave comments yet, so this will have to be an answer..

Lucas is correct, but you must remember that this will also change the color of the characters shown when you `:set list`.  If you are attempting to hide these tildes, you will also hide those characters.

Answer (score 2):

For standard Vim 8.x, the following works:

```
:highlight EndOfBuffer ctermfg=*color*
```

This colors tildes at the end of buffers into a specifically determined color.

For gVim 8.x, the following is smoother:

```
:highlight EndOfBuffer guifg=bg
```

This is better since it colors tildes at the end of buffers into the color of the background, effectively making such tildes transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of neovim let you override the fillchar and has a bit of special casing if you make it a space.

```
set fcs=eob:\
```

^^^ *There is an escaped space at the end*

YMMV with vim or with older versions.

Answer (score -1):

You could try a new color scheme.

```
:colors <colorscheme name>
```

You can find the names of the schemes installed on your system in $VIMRUNTIME/colors/
Also, if the 'bg' option isn't set properly, those little tildes can be hard to see.