# How do I change the character Vim uses to number blank lines in a buffer?

Tags: vim

Currently, when my window is bigger than the buffer being displayed, blank lines *beyond the end of file* are shown with the `~` characters in the line number column. I would prefer for the line number column for those lines to be blank. Is it possible to make it so?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294790/tilde-color-in-vim/

Comment: Although I hadn't seen that question when asking this, I think it's not a duplicate in that this is asking about changing the character, not the colour of that character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to not display a ~ for blank lines in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813059/is-it-possible-to-not-display-a-for-blank-lines-in-vim)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the tilde character that
Vim uses to show the lines beyond the end of a file (without modifying
the source code).

A viable workaround is to hide those tildes by configuring the
`NonText` highlight group, which is used for displaying them,
so that its foreground color is the same as the background one:

```
:highlight NonText ctermfg=bg guifg=bg
```

However, this approach is not a complete solution, because this
highlighting group is also used for rendering the list characters
(see `:help 'list'` and `:help 'listchars'`), making it impossible to
specify highlighting just for the beyond-last-line markings.

Starting with version 8 (see `:helpg Patch 7.4.2213`), Vim allows
to highlight the filler lines after the last line in a buffer using
a separate highlighting group called `EndOfBuffer`:

```
:highlight EndOfBuffer ctermfg=bg guifg=bg
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do use listchars, so that won't help. Thanks for answering though!

Comment: I really hope vim fixes this.

Comment: @devth:  Yeah, it shouldn't be a complicated change to allow users to configure the character through the `fillchars` option, for example.

Answer (score 8):

As of Vim 8.0, the color of the filler line character (~) can be changed indepedently by configuring the `EndOfBuffer` highlight group:

```
highlight EndOfBuffer ctermfg=bg guifg=bg
```