# Is it possible to not display a ~ for blank lines in Vim/Neovim?

Tags: vim, macvim, neovim

Is it possible to not display a ~ for blank lines in Vim?

This confuses Mac Vim's scrollbar, and I quite don't like these tildes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tilde color in vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294790/tilde-color-in-vim)

Comment: Well, nope. I actually saw this question before, and it's not a matter of color. I'd like to get rid of those completely. They trigger a weird scrolling in MacVim (so that you can scroll "too low", so that only the last line is visible at the top) : http://i.imgur.com/8f4u6.png -> http://i.imgur.com/vDMk3.png

Comment: @Ecco The tilde's are not triggering the scroll issue, the scroll function is based on the first line visible not the range of lines visible. Depending on your GUI you may be able to adjust that, but messing with the tildes is not going to be the route to get there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As jamessan said, you can’t disable them. The scrolling behavior isn’t specific to MacVim, either — it works the same way in the terminal and in gvim:

[image: Screenshot of this in the terminal]

Instead of seeing this as a problem, what you should do is learn to see this as part of Vim’s flexibility. For example, you can use the <kbd>zt</kbd> command to scroll the current line to the top of the screen, regardless of where in the file it is. This can make it easier to write macros that do some work and then scroll back to where you were. The commands <kbd><C-E></kbd> and <kbd><C-Y></kbd> are made simpler because of this, as is the `'scrolloffset'` option.

If you must, retrain your brain to think of Vim’s scrollbar as mapping to which line is on top, instead of which screenful is visible.

Comment: Is there a way to have zz put cursor at center even if current line is at the start of file? Filling the lines above the SOF with '~'?

Comment: *"Instead of seeing this as a problem, what you should do is learn to see this as part of Vim’s flexibility...."* - Another way to look at it is, the tools should work for you; and not vice versa.

Answer (score 59):

`:hi NonText guifg=bg`

That command should set the color of non text characters to be the same as the background color.

Comment: For some reason I still do get some ghostly tildes in Vim-Qt and Vim-GTK after this command. Here's [a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/cVUM6t0.png).

Comment: `:highlight EndOfBuffer ctermfg=gb` did it for me

Answer (score 57):

**Vim 8.x**:

You can now change the color just for the end of the buffer `~`:

`highlight EndOfBuffer ctermfg=black ctermbg=black`

[See changelog for Vim 8.x.](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/version8.txt#L363-L364)

Comment: Also works for neovim 0.5 (just tested my current version), cheers!

Comment: `:highlight EndOfBuffer ctermfg=gb` did it for me

Answer (score 11):

For NeoVim, you can set the `fillchars` value for `eob` to a space character and that will effectively hide it. *(This might not work for plain Vim)*.

**In Lua (Nvim 0.5+):**

```lua
vim.wo.fillchars='eob: '
```

**In VimScript:**

```
set fillchars=eob:\
```

---

**Note:** Calling the above will override your `fillchars` value for other items as well (if set), so use this as a reference to set multiple values together:

```
set fillchars=eob:\ ,fold:\ ,vert:\│
```

Or use `set fillchars+=...` to append it your existing values.

Comment: `set fillchars=eob:\ ` worked for me in Vim. I actually decided I like to see this, but don't like tildes, so I set it to `set fillchars=eob:-` instead.

Comment: `vim.wo.fillchars='eob: '` will only set it for current window. To set globally, use `vim.opt.fillchars='eob: '`.

Answer (score 8):

The tilde `~` characters are meant to remind the user that those lines are not part of buffer content.

The above highlight trick will *hide* the ~ character, but it is still there. For some terminals, this may not even work. If you happen to be a Neovim user, you can use [`fillchars`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27fillchars%27) option to change the end of buffer symbol like this:

```
set fillchars=fold:\ ,vert:\│,eob:\ ,msgsep:‾
```

This will use space instead of `~` for end of buffer, effectively *hiding* the annoying `~`.

You may also be interested in discussions [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2067).

Comment: How can I make this persist. because when I close and start vim again. The tilde characters reappear

Answer (score 5):

You can't disable them, but you can change your colorscheme such that the [NonText](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#hl-NonText) highlight group is colored the same as the Normal highlight group.  However, this affects more than just the end of document tildes.

I doubt that it's actually "confusing" MacVim's scrollbar and if it is, then that's a bug in the patching that MacVim does.

Comment: I think his confusion arises from the full screen height of `~` characters, which lets you always scroll down until one line of text is visible.

Comment: Indeed, jleedev nailed it. For instance, look here : http://i.imgur.com/8f4u6.png . There is a scrollbar displayed, that lets me scroll so that only "line four" is visible". Which doesn't make sense, really.

Comment: As jleedev described, it does make sense since you can scroll the buffer until the last line is the only thing displayed.  At that point, the scrollbar will be at the bottom of its channel.

Answer (score 5):

For Lua, instead of:

```
vim.wo.fillchars='eob: '
```

Use the following:

```
vim.opt.fillchars = { eob = ' ' }
```

The former does not persist for new buffers, while the latter does.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the '~' being a reminder that this portion of editor is not part of the content, a suitable proxy is to use line numbers, which is often enabled in many configurations anyway. That makes the '~' superfluous in those configurations.