# Is there a way to remove tildes when writing in Vim Goyo?

Tags: vim, tilde

When I open Goyo I would like the tildes and carets to be gone. Is this possible? [image: Image of vim when Goyo is up]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to not display a ~ for blank lines in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813059/is-it-possible-to-not-display-a-for-blank-lines-in-vim)

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Vim 8.1:

`:highlight EndOfBuffer ctermfg=black`

This will not properly remove the tildes but this will allow you to set their colors, and to choose one as close as possible to your terminal background.

In order to find the color available in Vim: http://www.calmar.ws/vim/256-xterm-24bit-rgb-color-chart.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Comment: @TobySpeight your comment doesnt follow: the help center defines programming tools as on-topic, and [so] (much to my delight/chagrin as a [vi.se] user) remains a hotbed of activity for vim questions. So, no? The answer is a good one and the Q is certainly not off-topic.

Comment: But vim is just an editor, not a programming tool (by your logic, all systems software would be "programming tools").  Certainly questions about programming Vim are on-topic, of course, but this is just about *using* and *configuring* the program.